# A script to delete and write over a file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I've been using this script on a previous intall of Debian. My new install is not a newer version (kept testing), but when I run it I get the error message "An error has occured while deleting ${*}."

```
#!/bin/bash
if zenity --question \
    --text "Do you really want to delete ${*} and write over it?" \
    --title "Delete and write over file"; then
  srm -r -l "$@" && \
  zenity --info --text "${*} has been deleted" \
      --title "Delete and write over file" ||
  zenity --error \
      --text "An error has occured while deleting ${*}." \
      --title "Delete and write over file"
fi
```

It comes from here: https://guide.boum.org/tomes/1_hors_connexions/unepage/#index75h3 (French)

As the title says, the goal is to delete and then write over a file to be sure the file has been "really" deleted.

I've never bash scripted before and I thought there might be a question of update/version that breaks the script since it's quite old.

Comment: What is `zenity`? Do you have to use it? If your goal is to make sure a file is "really" deleted (and it's not possible to undelete it), AND if you can use an external binary in your bash script, you should do the deletion with `shred -u`

Comment: What do you mean by "can't run"? Do you get any errors?

Comment: As I wrote, I have never bash scrited. I guess `zenity` is [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity)

Comment: @choroba see updated topic

Comment: So do you get error messages for `zenity` or for `srm` or both?

Comment: The script as such is just a wrapper, the real work is done by `srm`. If you really require a GUI to run it, creating a new script is probably far beyond your realistic abilities.

Comment: @tripleee I guess srm fails and then zenity prints the error message.

Comment: meh, `secure-delete` was not installed. Sorry for the stupid question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian package [`secure-delete`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/secure-delete) was not installed.